# Reusing loops in django templates

Tags: django

I was wondering if there's a way to repeat a loop with new objects gathered through jquery/ajax, for example i have `{% for car in cars %}` do something, then after getting new car objects through an ajax call I want to discard the current objects and display the new objects using the same loop. Is that possible? This is for implementing a search function, I initially show some objects but I have a search box for people to find specific objects. I thought of returning ready made html and replacing the html directly but that's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach (I think) for doing this, is:

1. have a view set up in Django, such as `view_cars` that outputs the result page based on a regular `GET` request.  The URL for this might look like `http://mysite.com/cars/1`.  The template for that view might look like this:

   ```
   <div id="cars">
       {% for car in cars %}
       <!-- output here! -->
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
   ```
2. have jQuery load the results with the `$.load()` function, like so:

   ```
   $("#cars").load("http://mysite.com/cars/2 #cars");
   ```

The search results will be automatically loaded into the `#cars` div, and you don't have to handle the special AJAX case within Django.

Answer (score 0):

Once the template has gone through the template engine there *are* no more loops, just text output in one form or another. But when you use AJAX it re-enters the top of the/a view, so you can reuse any loops you like at that point.